# OnResquestPermissionResult from Adapter

Tags: android, permissions, adapter

I Have a BaseAdapter with a List of all requires permissions for use correctly the app.

I need to, after onClick in one of them, request the permission and check if is granted or not.

For request, I am using

> ActivityCompat.requestPermissions

but I do not know how to get the results.

Is it possible to call O

> nRequestpermissionsResultCallback

to know the answer of the user?

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

so first i implement  in the Adapter
        **implements ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback**
then it require one Overide method

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        //  it is not work here  onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == storagePermission) {

            // getPosts(false);

            if (grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "Please allow permission to Continue", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



            }

            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
              Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), " Permissions Granted Succecfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        //here i load my method  that i want to run 
            }

        }
    }
```

now problem is this **onRequestPermissionsResult** is not call from adapter instead 
adapter triger **onRequestPermissionsResult** of the mainActivity  Attach with the Adapter

so in main Activity i create this and run **onRequestPermissionsResult** of adapter by passing 
 **adapterPosts.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode,permissions,grantResults);**

```
  @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == storagePermission) {

            // getPosts(false);

            if (grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
           //permission not granted
            }

            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
               //permission granted

                adapterPosts.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode,permissions,grantResults);
                //loadImageIntent();
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To check the permission (in this example it's a permission to use the camera):

```
   int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
   if (permissionCheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
            // permission is not granted yet, let's ask for it
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                    MyActivity.cameraRequestCode);
   } else {
            // permission is already granted
   }
```

If ActivityCompat.requestPermissions is run, then a dialogue appears for the user, after which you can catch the result by overriding the Activity's onRequestPermissionsResult like this:

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MyActivity.cameraRequestCode: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                   // action when permission granted
                } else {
                    // action when permission denied
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

MyActivity.cameraRequestCode is a static int, can be any unique int value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I want to implement the callback on the adapter not in the activity. instead if I try to implement in the activity the method not found to override, don'tt know why.

Comment: Sadly onRequestPermissionsResult can be overridden only on an activity or a fragment. If you want the adapter to handle the result, you have to pass it from the activity/fragment to the adapter.

Comment: how to pass to the adapter !

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter class

```
class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Your adapter.MyViewHolder> implements ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback{`//enter code here`}
```

It will override the onRequestPermissionsResult

Comment: Unfortunately onRequestPermissionsResult does not fired on the adapter !

Answer (score 0):

I have a same problem in RecylclerView.Adapter and I use this section in permission request method

```
private void requestCallPhonePerm() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
            Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        onItemCallListener.itemCallPhone(itemPhones);
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity)context,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CALL_PHONE);
    } else {
        ((MainActivity)context).callPhone(itemPhones);
    }
}
```

It's important to use **(Activity)context** in "requestPermissions" method to be invoked callback in container activity of your adapter

And in my MainActivity that contain recycler I use overrided request permission result normally.

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch(requestCode){
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS:
                if(grantResults.length>0
                        &&grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    new LoadContacts().execute();
                }
                break;
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CALL_PHONE:
                if(grantResults.length>0&&grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    callPhone(phones);
                }else{

                }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this from custom class. My custom class is derived from `AppCompatActivity`. Also you need to pass Activity context to your custom class and do whatever you need with it.

```
public bool AreStorageAndCamPermissionsGranted(Activity context)
        {
            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                if (
                            context.CheckSelfPermission(Manifest.Permission.Camera)!= Android.Content.PM.Permission.Granted
                          || context.CheckSelfPermission(Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage) != Android.Content.PM.Permission.Granted
                          || context.CheckSelfPermission(Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage) != Android.Content.PM.Permission.Granted)
                {
                    ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(context, new String[]
                   {
                                Manifest.Permission.Camera,
                                Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage,
                                Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage,
                   }, REQUEST_PERMISSION_CODE);
                }
            return true;
        }
```

`